# Anonymous (privacy-preserving) random walk

Tags: network, privacy, anonymity, random, machine-learning

Quoting this paper - SmartWalk (https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2976749.2978319):

> For graph privacy, strong link privacy relies on deep perturbation to
>   the original graph, indicating a large random walk length. However, as
>   the ﬁxed random walk length increases, the perturbed graph gradually
>   approaches to a random graph, incurring a significant loss of utility.

They propose a machine-learning based approach to determining the appropriate random walk length as a trade-off between utility and security/privacy. **However, is there (at all) an anonymous or privacy-preserving method of conducting a random walk itself?**

Comment: Migrated here from the crypto site because I hope that the experts here have a bit more knowledge about this subject.